# CSS Navigation bar issue

Tags: html, css, list, inline, navigationbar

So I am having this problem, I am trying to make a simple navigation bar where the LI

```
body {
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: Tahoma;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
    a {
        color: #3D91EB;
        text-decoration:none
    }
    a:link {
        color: #3D91EB;
    }
    a:visited {
        color: #3D91EB;
    }
    a:active {
        color: #2C82DE;
    }
    .navigation {
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #383838;
        color: whiteSmoke;
        list-style-type:none;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .navigation ul {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    li {
        display: inline;
    }
    .container {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color: #9C9C9C;
        height: 500px;
        width: 600px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

and here is my HTML

```
 <div class="navigation">
          <ul>
               <li>Test 1</li>
               <li>Test 2</li>
               <li>Test 3</li>
          </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="container" style="">
         Testasdf
 </div>
```

If anyone could please help me fix my issue, that would be great!

Comment: your question seems to be incomplete

Comment: So what is your issue/problem.  You never stated what the problem is?

Comment: Do not edit out the original question once an answer was given, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one :-

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/skxC6/)

Update this :-

```
.navigation ul {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's because unordered lists automatically have CSS padding and margins on them. You have to clear them first:

```
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```